# Invalid IN query/statement with to much '?' parameter

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

There are limitations for some databases how much parameter '?' can exist in an IN statement e.g. in MS SQL the limit is 1000.

However, when I create an IN query with a Pageable, this limitation is not considered. For example, if I search for 1200 names, it will be 1200 '?' used in the IN statement. This crashes under MS SQL with the following error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 1200 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.
```

Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, UUID> {

    Page<Course> findAllByNameIn(Collection<String> names, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Test class:

```
   @SpringBootTest
    public class SqlQueryTest {
    
        @Autowired
        private CourseRepository courseRepository;
    
        @Test
        public void testInQuery() {
    
            final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    
            IntStream.range(0, 1200).forEach(count -> {
                final Course course = new Course();
                final String name = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10);
                names.add(name);
                course.setName(name);
                courseRepository.save(course);
            });
    
            courseRepository.findAllByNameIn(names, Pageable.ofSize(500));
    
        }
}
```

Statement looks like

```
select
    course0_.id as id1_0_,
    course0_.name as name2_0_ 
from
    course course0_ 
where
    course0_.name in (
        ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ....
```

I've also tried EclipseLink Query hints batch_size and batch_type IN. However, without success. See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_batch_size.htm

So my question is that a bug if an invalid statement is executed? Do I have to take care of it myself and split up the selects.

When I load a relationship in an IN statement, the batch size is works and several selects are executed with IN

Is it possible to execute individual selects (e.g. findByName) and execute them in batch?

Comment: Which statement do you consider invalid yet executed in your case?

Comment: Statement looks like: 
       select
        course0_.id as id1_0_,
        course0_.name as name2_0_ 
    from
        course course0_ 
    where
        course0_.name in ( (
            ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?  ...)

Comment: See here with a JDBC Template there is a "workaround" 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-in-list#large

Comment: Ok, by "executed invalid statement" you mean "tried to execute invalid statement which caused database error". Initially I understood that DB run some queries with more than 1000 params. Pageable is used to get part of results, when you need it with large set of IN params JPA might give up - it is a quite complex problem that requires multiple queries and processing results on application side (merging results, sorting, removing results outside of those set in Pageable). As a rule of thumb I never use JPA for complex tasks, it is too complex already, debugging it might be a nightmare.

Comment: If a IN query is executed with more than 1000 placeholder it will faill.

See JDBCTemplate documentation
' Be careful when passing in many values. The JDBC standard does not guarantee that you can use more than 100 values for an in expression list. Various databases exceed this number, but they usually have a hard limit for how many values are allowed. For example, Oracle’s limit is 1000.
'

My question is how can i solve this issue with spring-data-jpa and a repository.


My expectation was that Pageable should work because it works properly with relationships.

Comment: the only JPA solution I see is to partition IN params (I like using [guava partition] method for this task (https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-)), merge & sort results in application and remove some of them if page size is smaller than number of results.

Comment: Yes this the current solution to use partition with the JDBC template. So there is no smarter solution with spring-data-jpa and queryhints directly?

Comment: You can use JPA with partitioned IN params. Now I think about it baeldung solution you linked could also be used with Hibernate API [https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction(java.lang.String)], so you could skip partitioning and still have JPA mapping done automatically.